# removing a table row after XmlHttpRequest complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I have an HTML table with a bunch of table rows, each has an id attribute and a delete button in a table cell. I bind an ajax call to the delete button with this:

```
$('.deletebutton').bind 'click', () ->
  id = $(this).attr "id" // getting my row id here
  $.ajax // sending my ajax request
    url: "/admin/delete/#{id}"
    type: 'POST'
    beforeSend: (jqXHR, settings) ->
      jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr('content'))
```

This works without any problem.  Now I add the following parameter to my ajax call to delete the table row, but it doesn't work.  I tried different things, but I can't figure this out.  Help please.

```
    success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
      $('tr[id=id]').remove() // I don't understand why my jQuery selector doesn't work here...
```

Comment: `$('#trid').remove()` use this

Comment: Your selector needs to be:  $('tr#' + id)

Comment: why can't I use this: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: use `$('#trid').remove()` or 0` $('tr#' + id)`

Comment: You can use the attribute selector but you haven't constructed it correctly. It would need to be $('tr[id="' + id + '"]')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain JavaScript ('cos I don't know CoffeeScript - sorry :-) ). 
Without the need to use the rows 'id'.

```
$('.deletebutton').click(function(){

   var rowToDelete = $(this).closest('tr');

    $.ajax({
       /* --- the rest of your params here --- */
        success: function() {
            rowToDelete.remove();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I'll take that as the answer, but what I used the construct you posted in the comments, since it was more along the lines of what I was initially doing.  Thanks.